# On smoothness of a function

Tags: functions

Consider the following function

$f(x) = \ln \left( {\cosh \left( {{{\left[ {\max \left( {0,x} \right)} \right]}^n}} \right)} \right)$

where $max(.)$ is max function, $ln$ is natural logarithmic function and $cosh$ is hyperbolic cosine function. Does the function belong to class $\mathcal{C}^2$ if $n>1$?

Note 1: Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness regarding class $\mathcal{C}^2$.

Note 2: My calculation shows the above statement is correct but I just want to be sure.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you provide the mainlines of your calculations?

Comment: Sorry, I just saw your comment. My calculation was almost the same as @Nicolas except I think the case he discussed for even and odd number is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ is a combination of smooth functions except for $\max(0,.)$ which is not differentiable at zero, we only need to check the regularity at zero.

Suppose that $n$ is not integer ; we then write
$$  f(x)=\left\{
       \begin{aligned}
         \ln\left(\cosh\left(x^n\right)\right) && \text{if $x>0$}\\
         0 && \text{if $x\leq0$} \\
       \end{aligned}
    \right.$$
because $f$ is not define for $x<0$ in that case (since $x^n=\exp\left(n\ln(x)\right)$). Then
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\ln\left(\cosh\left(x^n\right)\right)=nx^{n-1}\tanh\left(x^n\right)\underset{x\to 0}{\longrightarrow}0$$
and hence
$$  f'(x)=\left\{
       \begin{aligned}
         nx^{n-1}\tanh\left(x^n\right) && \text{if $x>0$}\\
         0 && \text{if $x\leq0$} \\
       \end{aligned}
    \right. $$
is continuous at zero. Now,
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}nx^{n-1}\tanh\left(x^n\right)=\frac{n^2x^{2(n-1)}}{\cosh\left(x^n\right)}+n(n-1)x^{n-2}\tanh\left(x^n\right)$$
and it suffices to check the limit at zero of the last term in the RHS of the above expression (since it is clear that the first one tends to zero because $n-1>0$).

If $n>2$, we are done. Now suppose that $1<n<2$ ; then we write $n=2-\varepsilon$ for $0<\varepsilon<1$ and we have
$$\frac{\tanh\left(x^n\right)}{x^{\varepsilon}}=\frac{x^n}{x^{\varepsilon}}+O\left(x^{3n-\varepsilon}\right)\underset{x\to 0}{\longrightarrow}0.$$

Now, we have to deal with the integer cases for $n$. If $n$ is even, then $\max(0,x^n)=x^n$, and if $n$ is odd, then $f$ can be written as in the first above equation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution and the time you spent. However, I should point that the last line is not necessary as 
$[max(0,x)]^n \ne [max(0,x^n)]$.

Comment: @RezaH.Khayyami Oh sorry, I misread your question : I had $\max\left(0,x^n\right)$ in mind.